# Adding table name to SQL query at runtime

Tags: python, pymssql

I write a method like below:

```
def add(self,table_name, tc_no, file_no):
    self._cursor.execute("select HastaId from {}".format(table_name)," where TC=%s and FileNo=%s",(tc_no,file_no))
    row = self._cursor.fetchone()
    return row
```

and I got an error

> TypeError: execute() takes at most 2 positional arguments (3 given)

I know the mistake in the `format()` . How can i use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea. Query parameters can only represent column *values*, not column or table *names*.

Therefore you *do* need to use string formatting to insert the table name into the SQL command text and then use query parameters to supply the values for the WHERE clause.

So, a construct like this will not work:

```python
crsr.execute(
        "select HastaId from %s where TC=%s and FileNo=%s",
        (table_name, tc_no, file_no))
```

but this will work

```python
crsr.execute(
        "select HastaId from [{}] where TC=%s and FileNo=%s".format(table_name),
        (tc_no, file_no))
```